# How to reference a git repository?

Tags: git, path

What should the actual path to a git repository 'file' be? It's common practise when cloning from github to do something like:

```
git clone https://user@github.com/repo.git
```

And I'm used to that.

If I init a repo on my local machine using git init, what is the 'git file' for me to reference? I'm trying tot setup [Capifony](http://capifony.org/) with a Symfony2 project and need to set the repository path. Specifying the folder of the repository isn't working. Is there a .git file for each repository I should be referencing?

Edit:

So for example, if I do the following:

mkdir /path/to/project
cd /path/to/project
git init

What should my path be to reference that git repo?

- /path/to/project?
- /path/to/project/?
- /path/to/project.git?
- /path/to/project/.git?

Edit2:

So this is an excerpt from the Capifony config:

```
set   :application,   "My App"
set   :deploy_to,     "/var/www/my-app.com"
set   :domain,        "my-app.com"

set   :scm,           :git
set   :repository,    "ssh-gitrepo-domain.com:/path/to/repo.git"

role  :web,           domain
role  :app,           domain, :primary => true

set   :use_sudo,      false
set   :keep_releases, 3
```

I need to set my repository to a local repo, which I've been trying to do with all combinations of the previous paths like:

```
set   :repository,    "file:///c:/path/to/repo.git"
```

But no path works to my (valid) git repo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use the command `git init` it initiates an repository in the folder your bash is located at that moment. It will create a folder `.git` and all the folders and files that belong to the same parent folder might be added to the git repository.

E.g.

[image: git init command]

Will result in:

[image: folder schema for a git repository]

Realize this is an hidden folder.

**EDIT**

To push to a local repository you will need to create a second repository using the command `git init --bare`, it will make the repository pushable. Let's consider you created the second repository at `c:/path/to/repo`, so, it will have the `.git` folder in it.

With your bash at the first git repo, use `git remote add origin file:///c:/path/to/repo`.

Then push the first repo to the origin by using `push origin --all`, it will push to the second repo you created.

Comment: So should I use that hidden .git folder as my path?

Comment: Can you give me an example of when you need the path?

Comment: I just saw your EDIT now, anyway, it is still not clear for me of when the hard path is needed.

Comment: I added a second edit with what I'm trying to do/an example.

Comment: If you want to make a local repository you will need to use the command `git init --bare` to initiate your repository you want to push to. Them, use the path without `.git`. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks, sorted that part of my problem, now I just have to iron out a few issues with Capifony. :) Thanks again.